# Simple way to detect browser or script

Tags: python, django

Complexities aside, what is the simplest quirty-and-dirty way to detect in a request whether that request was issues by a CLI program, such as `curl`, or whether it was by a browser? Here is what I'm trying to figure out:

```
def view(request):
    if request.is_from_browser:
        return HTML_TEMPLATE
    else:
        return JSON
```

Comment: How about using `User-Agent` header? (NOTE: Programs like `curl` easily change http headers)

Comment: Why do you want to do this? there are many dofferent headers, and picking the right one requires knowlege of the intended purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Request.is_ajax()` checks if the `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` header equals `XMLHttpRequest`. This is becoming an *"industry standard"* among *web* frameworks/libraries to separate *Ajax calls* from normal requests. But it depends on cooperation from the client side to actually set the header. There's no 100 % foolproof way of detecting browser, client, Ajax etc without this cooperation.

Btw, why do you need to know what's calling?

Answer (score 0):

Somthing in the HTTP request headers,  I'd first try using the `Accept` header.  with the accept header the client can specify what sort of content it wants.this puts the responsibily on the client.

Comment: This should be a comment, it only answers the first part of the question.

Comment: @A.J. there are two parts?